# Reduce value in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am looking to have the value of a reduce function. This is my dimension and reduce function:

```
var RespondDim       =  ndx.dimension(function (d) { return true;});
var ntotal           =  RespondDim.group().reduce(
                            function(p, d) { 
                                if(d.Respond_Id in p.Respond_Ids){
                                    p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id]++;
                                }
                                else {
                                    p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id] = 1;
                                    p.RespondCount++;
                                }
                                return p;
                            },
                            function (p, d) {
                                p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id]--;
                                if(p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id] === 0){
                                    delete p.Respond_Ids[d.Respond_Id];
                                    p.RespondCount--;
                                }
                                return p;
                            },
                            function () {
                                return {
                                    RespondCount: 0,
                                    Respond_Ids: {}
                                };
                             });
```

Then I am having  `ntotal.all()= {key: true, value: {RespondCount: 3, Respond_Ids: {258: 2, 261: 2, 345: 3}}}`

All I want is to access `RespondCount` and use it in some calculation I am performing outside of cross filter/dc... I have tried `ntotal.all().value.RespondCount` but it seems not working. The goal is  How do I do that ? Thank you!

Comment: Try `ntotal.all()[0].value.RespondCount`. The group `all` and `top` methods return arrays. In your case it is an array with one value, but still an array. You can use your browser dev tools to debug or print out values to the console with `console.log`, which will help you figure out these problems.